# Proxy shared library (sharedlib, shlib, so) for ELF?

Tags: c, dll, proxy, shared-libraries, elf

On Windows, it's more or less common to create "proxy DLLs" which take place of the original DLL and forward calls to it (after any additional actions as needed). You can read about it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/CreateYourProxyDLLs.aspx) and [here](http://aluigi.altervista.org/mytoolz.htm#dllproxyskel) for example.

However, shlib munging culture under Linux is quite different. It starts with the fact that LD_PRELOAD is the builtin feature with ld.so under Linux, which simply injects separate shlib into process and uses any symbols it defines as override. And that "injection" technique seems to define whole direction of thought - here's [a typical ELF hacking tool](http://www.eresi-project.org/wiki/TheELFsh) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029940/patching-code-symbols-into-a-dynamic-linked-elf-binary), where gentleman seems to have the same usecase as me, but starts with asking how he can patch existing binaries.

No, thanks. I don't want to inject into or modify something which is nor mine. All I want to do is to make a standalone proxy shlib which will call out to the original. Ideally, there would be a tool which can be fed with the original .so and create a C source code which would just redirect to original's functions, while letting me easily override anything I want. So, where's such tool? ;-) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using `LD_PRELOAD` doesn't really involve modifying something which isn't yours, and the injection isn't all that different from normal dynamic library loading. The “typical ELF hacking tool” from the ERESI project is unrelated to `LD_PRELOAD`. You should not be afraid of it. A good introduction to writing `LD_PRELOAD`-able “proxies” is [here](https://rafalcieslak.wordpress.com/2013/04/02/dynamic-linker-tricks-using-ld_preload-to-cheat-inject-features-and-investigate-programs/).

That being said, if you want to create a system-wide proxy for some library, you might argue that globally setting `LD_PRELOAD` (and thus loading your proxy into every binary that ever runs on your system) is undesirable. It is commonly used to override functions from glibc by tools such as [libeatmydata](https://github.com/stewartsmith/libeatmydata) or [socksify](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/dante-client/socksify.1.en.html), but if you're overriding a function in a library that is bigger and/or less widespread than glibc, it makes sense to try to find another approach, to really create a proxy for just that one library.

One such approach is to use `patchelf --replace-needed` or `--add-needed` to hardcode the full pathname of the original library and then make sure the proxy library is found first by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`¹. So, the complete procedure is:

1. create an `LD_PRELOAD`-able library that overrides some functions of the original one (test that it works using only `LD_PRELOAD` before proceeding further!)
2. compile and link this library with the original library so that `ldd libwrapper-foo.so` includes something like:
   `libfoo.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfoo.so.0 (0x0000deadbeef0000)`
3. hardcode the full path using `patchelf`:
   `patchelf --replace-needed libfoo.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfoo.so.0 libwrapper-foo.so`
4. symlink `libwrapper-foo.so` to `libfoo.so.0`
5. now `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ldd $(which program-that-uses-libfoo)` should include these lines:
   `libfoo.so.0 => ./libfoo.so.0 (0x0000dead56780000)`
   `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfoo.so.0 (0x0000dead1234000000)`
6. set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to full path to the wrapper library in your `.bashrc` or somewhere

A real-life example of such proxy libary is [my wrapper for libpango](https://github.com/liskin/dotfiles/tree/56f802d94df5225ef74e027dff0741b97e7ef018/src/pango-force-subpixel-positioning) that enables subpixel positioning for all applications.

---

¹) It might also be possible to put this proxy library into `/usr/local/lib`, but `ldconfig` (the tool that updates shared libraries cache) refuses to use libraries with hardcoded absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

[apitrace](https://github.com/apitrace/apitrace) is a tool which covers detailed tracing of graphic libs (OpenGL, DirectX) calls for a number of platform. It's probably too detailed and complex for generic solution, but at least provides some reference and affinity.